# Restriction on size of matrix?

Tags: latex

The difference between this code:

```
\begin{align*}
    I &= \begin{pmatrix}
         0   & 1  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  0  &  0.5  &  0.5   &  1 &  0    & 1  & 1\\
         0   & 1  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  0  &  0.5  &  0.5   &  1 &  0    & 1  & 1\\
         1   & 1  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  0  &  0.5  &  0.5   &  1 &  0    & 1  & 0\\
         1   & 1  &  0    &  1    &  1  &  0    &  0     &  1 &  1    & 0  & 0\\
         1   & 1  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  0  &  0.5  &  1     &  1 &  1    & 0  & 0\\
         0   & 0  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  0  &  0.5  &  1     &  1 &  0    & 0  & 1\\
         0   & 0  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  1  &  1    &  1     &  1 &  1    & 0  & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
```

which does not compile, and this one which does compile

```
\begin{align*}
    I &= \begin{pmatrix}
         0   & 1  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  0  &  0.5  &  0.5   &  1 &  0    & 1\\
         0   & 1  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  0  &  0.5  &  0.5   &  1 &  0    & 1\\
         1   & 1  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  0  &  0.5  &  0.5   &  1 &  0    & 1\\
         1   & 1  &  0    &  1    &  1  &  0    &  0     &  1 &  1    & 0\\
         1   & 1  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  0  &  0.5  &  1     &  1 &  1    & 0\\
         0   & 0  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  0  &  0.5  &  1     &  1 &  0    & 0\\
         0   & 0  &  0.5  &  0.5  &  1  &  1    &  1     &  1 &  1    & 0\\
    \end{pmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
```

is that the one tha does compile does not have the last column. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~svs/latex.html), the max number of columns a matrix can have by default is 10. You can override this by using the command

`\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{n}`

where `n` is the number of desired columns.